# how to set the SCRENSHOT_VIA_USB=true in calabash android .

Tags: android, calabash

I need to take the screenshots of the alert box in the emulator. I am just getting the back ground images and not the popup/alert box .

I don't know exactly  to set this SCREENSHOT_VIA_USB=true .

Can someone help me in this ?

Answer (score 2):

```
  if ENV["SCREENSHOT_VIA_USB"] == "true"
    device_args = "-s #{@serial}" if @serial
    screenshot_cmd = "java -jar #{File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'lib', 'screenShotTaker.jar')} #{path} #{device_args}"
    log screenshot_cmd
    raise "Could not take screenshot" unless system(screenshot_cmd)
  else
    begin
      res = http("/screenshot")
    rescue EOFError
      raise "Could not take screenshot. App is most likely not running anymore."
    end
    File.open(path, 'wb') do |f|
      f.write res
    end
  end
```

SCREENSHOT_VIA_USB is a environment var, try :

```
 export SCREENSHOT_VIA_USB=true
```